# Вопрос про внешние ключи MySQL

Tags: mysql

Как сделать автоматическую смену внешнего ключа в таблице при удалении родительской записи в другой таблице?

Comment: причем тут ключ и запись? Вы понимаете что такое внешний ключ и как он работает?

Comment: При создании внешнего ключа можно указать, что делать при удалении родителя. В вашем случае можно объявить on delete set null или set default. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @Mike, дружище, ты кажется помог мне во второй раз :) Искал как раз что-то вроде "SET DEFAULT"